# Drools - represent sheet in Rules to be applied per column not row

Tags: drools

I have many spread sheets that are structured like this :

```
| Column A | Column B |
---------------------
| ____ a ___ | ____ A2 ____ |
---------------------
| ____ b ___ | ____ B4 ____ |
---------------------
| ____ c ___ | ____ S4 ____ |
---------------------
```

Note that the lists are huge.

I have two strings, if first one exists in any row in column A AND second string exists in any row in column B then the some action must be applied.

Can somebody help what is the best way to represent these rules, as I know in decision table action is applied per each row.

Comment: These spreadsheets aren't rules - they are just collections of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use some library to read a spreadsheet into an object according to the following class:

```
class TwoColumns {
    private List<String> colA;
    private List<String> colB;
    // constructor, getters,...
}
```

All strings of column A are in colA, all of column B are in colB. - Define another class with two String values:

```
class TwoStrings {
    private String strA;
    private String strB;
    // constructor, getters,...
}
```

Insert a TwoColumns object and one TwoStrings object and use this rule:

```
rule findTwoStrings
when
    TwoStrings( $a: strA, $b: strB )
    TwoColumns( colA contains $a, colB contains $b )
then
    System.out.println( $a + " and " + $b + " can be found" );
end
```

If you need to search in those "many spreadsheets" at the same time, add a name to the TwoColumns object so you can identify the matching one.